# Yup validation using this in standalone const

Tags: typescript, yup

I am using React with TypeScript, and I need to check if my groupID is in list of arrays of [2, 3, 4].

Am not sure, that my validationSchema  is good or not, but I have a problem with this keywrod, becaue this not exists, in const.
My validationSchema  const is a standalone file.

Any help?!

```
export const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape
({
      text: Yup
            .string()
            .defined()
            .max(2048, "Az üzenet szövege túl hosszú,"),
      groupID: Yup
              .number()
              .min(1),
      queryParam: Yup
                 .string()
                 .when("is_in_list",
                 {
                        is: [2, 3, 4].includes(this.parent.groupID),
                        then: Yup
                              .string()
                              .defined("Kötelező mező."),
                        otherwise: Yup
                                   .string()
                                   .nullable()
                }),
      isVoteType: Yup
                 .boolean(),
      positiveAnswer: Yup
                      .string()
                      .when("isVoteType",
                      {
                              is: true,
                              then: Yup.string()
                                    .required("Kötelező mező.")
                        }),
      negativeAnswer: Yup
                      .string()
                      .when("isVoteType",
                      {
                              is: true,
                              then: Yup.string()
                                       .required("Kötelező mező.")
                      })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as Yup from "yup";

export const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape
({
      text: Yup
            .string()
            .required()
            .max(2048, "Az üzenet szövege túl hosszú,"),
      groupID: Yup
              .number()
              .min(1),
      queryParam: Yup
                 .string()
                 .when("groupID",
                 {
                        is: (groupID: number) =>  groupID > 1,
                        then: Yup.mixed()
                                 .required("Kötelező mező.")
                  }),
      isVoteType: Yup
                 .boolean(),
      positiveAnswer: Yup
                      .string()
                      .when("isVoteType",
                      {
                              is: (isVoteType: boolean) => isVoteType,
                              then: Yup.string()
                                       .required("Kötelező mező.")
                        }),
      negativeAnswer: Yup
                      .string()
                      .when("isVoteType",
                      {
                              is: (isVoteType: boolean) => isVoteType,
                              then: Yup.string()
                                       .required("Kötelező mező.")
                      })
});
```